# How do I easily (and efficiently) delete a single element from array?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following:

```
a = np.array([0,0,64,64,100,100,130,130,0,183,208,0,255])
```

and I wish to delete **a single, specific** value from this array, e.g., a single 130

to yield:

```
[0,0,64,64,100,100,130,0,183,208,0,255]
```

It is irrelevant which  is deleted.

I do not wish to remove all '130's, in this example (i.e., **not** `a[a != 130]`). 
Computational efficiency is a concern as I have a few large arrays to churn through.

Comment: Removing an arbitrary element is an expensive operation. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @Krumelur. Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have become aware of that the hard way ahah. I need remove numbers as candidates for another operation.

Comment: So whats your logic behind this output? do you want to remove it with index?

Comment: do you have lists with many repetitions, but limited distinct values? if so, one could keep a list or a dictionary where the key/position is the number, and the value at that key/pos. is the count. from there you can easily increment or decrement the values. In this instance I would use a numpy array...

Comment: @InNoam Is the order of the elements important?

Comment: @Krumelur . No, order is also irrelevant.

Comment: @InNoam it might help if you can say what you are using this for? For example, if you are looking to remove duplicates there is [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

Comment: @YXD I apologize. I was too terse in my explanation.  So, I am randomly assigning colours to shapes in a figure. The array represents the "pool" of possible "homogenous RGB" colours I can use, e.g., `color = 64 --> (color, color, color)`. Once an array element has been used, it cannot  be used again. The problem, of course, is that sometimes I can use a colour twice or three times, other times only once. Shapes are to be generated until the "color pool" is depleted via a `while` loop

Comment: @InNoam See my updated answer. In that case, you could use my last suggestion and set the used colors to transparent or something, then you can even avoid `resize`. However, there are probably better data structures for your problem (depending on the number of colors etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swap the element with the last element, and then resize the array.**

I made a small test, using the naïve ndarray.delete function, e.g.:

```
A = numpy.delete(A, 1)
```

versus swapping

```
A[1] = A[-1]
A.resize((len(A) - 1,))
```

EDIT: @YXD suggested replacing the resize with creation of a view

```
A[1] = A[-1]
A = A[:-1]
```

which is a lot better (just my knowledge of numpy is limited) and nicely packages the suggestion in the end of my answer.

The latter destroys the ordering of the array, but removes the need to `memcpy` the a large part of the array for each delete.

A small performance test:

```
# Naïve approach
print timeit.timeit("""
import numpy
A = numpy.array(range(0,10000))
while len(A) > 10:
    A = numpy.delete(A, 1)
""", number=10)

# Swap, resize
print timeit.timeit("""
import numpy
A = numpy.array(range(0,10000))
while len(A) > 10:
    A[1] = A[-1]
    A.resize((len(A) - 1,))
""", number=10)

# Swap, create view
print timeit.timeit("""
import numpy
A = numpy.array(range(0,10000))
while len(A) > 10:
    A[1] = A[-1]
    A = A[:-1]
""", number=10)

>>> 2.52913403511 
>>> 0.14426112175
>>> 0.0972230434418
```

So it looks like the `ndarray` is really implemented as a C array (which of course makes a lot of sense). The swapping is an old C trick that I learned ages ago :)

Comment: You don't have to delete - you can do `A = A[:-1]` which will return a view without the last element.

Comment: This is definitely a technique I'll have to remember. I thought I had something going with my comment, but this is truly a better solution as far as complexity and preserving the original functionality.

Comment: @Krumelur Haha, thanks for the shoutout, but you should probs give YXD the credit...

Comment: Thank you so very much! That feeling when you see the number `0.0972230434418`...Bliss! ahah

Comment: My apologies, I failed to see that it was two separate comments :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete array elements. Instead you can create secondary array with all desired elements and then remove the original array.

Comment: This is probably what the asker discovered the hard way :)